# POST to /requests results in semi-permanent 409 current_trip_exists error, GET shows no_current_trip

Tags: uber-api

We're getting a 409 current_trip_exists error when we make a post request. When we make a get request to the /requests/current endpoint it says no current trip and when we make a get request to the /requests/requestId endpoint it says the last trip completed. The request/responses below demonstrate what is happening.

This behavior does not happen in the Sandbox. The user is not currently on a ride.

#### Steps to Reproduce

The following steps successfully reproduced the buggy behavior three times.

1. After a user has completed a ride, use the API to order a ride in a different region. For example, we'd complete trips in Palo Alto and then order trips in Seattle.
2. Call the driver of the second trip and ask them to cancel the ride.
3. Reorder the ride in your second destination.

From that point forward for about 24 hours, the user will experience a current_trip_exists error when they try ordering rides. It doesn't affect all lat/long/productId's but I've included a list of lat/long/productId's affected at the end of this post.

I think this might be happening because Uber sometimes finds a second driver when the first one cancels. We're getting the driver_canceled status and firing a new POST request right after, but Uber may be using that account to find a new driver. I'm not sure though, because the 409 error continues to happen for a really long time and it will work in certain lat/longs but not others.

When a ride is taken on the account through the phone it clears up the error.

*To be continued...*

#### POST Request to /v1/requests

```
curl --request POST \
--url https://api.uber.com/v1/requests \
  --header 'authorization: Bearer xxxx' \
  --header 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --header 'postman-token: 5b663d39-3600-645c-27c3-339cbba4d239' \
  --data '{"product_id": "33de8094-3dc4-4ca9-8f67-243275f57623","start_latitude": 39.237713,"start_longitude": -94.43628029999999}'
```

#### Response

```
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Geo-System: wgs-84
Content-Length: 109
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Tue, 04 Apr 2017 20:16:19 GMT
Server: nginx
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=604800
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block 

    {
      "meta": {},
      "errors": [
        {
          "status": 409,
          "code": "current_trip_exists",
          "title": "The user is currently on a trip."
        }
      ]
    }
```

But when I make a GET request to check on if the user is in a trip:

#### GET Request to v1/requests/current

```
curl --request GET \
  --url https://api.uber.com/v1/requests/current \
  --header 'authorization: Bearer xxxx' \
  --header 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --header 'postman-token: 3ba89d75-071c-a24f-ce5e-22d1671c4d4b'
```

#### Response

```
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Encoding →gzip
Content-Type →application/json
Date →Wed, 05 Apr 2017 16:48:33 GMT
Server →nginx
Strict-Transport-Security →max-age=604800
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
X-Content-Type-Options →nosniff
X-XSS-Protection →1; mode=block
{
  "meta": {},
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": 404,
      "code": "no_current_trip",
      "title": "User is not currently on a trip."
    }
  ]
}
```

and then finally when I pull up the request of the last successful requestId this account has:

#### GET Request to v1/requests/906cff4d-5f05-4d46-9afd-1fdce67a0378

```
curl --request GET \
  --url https://api.uber.com/v1/requests/906cff4d-5f05-4d46-9afd-1fdce67a0378 \
  --header 'authorization: Bearer xxxx' \
  --header 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --header 'postman-token: 3ba89d75-071c-a24f-ce5e-22d1671c4d4b'
```

#### Response

```
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Encoding →gzip
Content-Geo-System →wgs-84
Content-Language →en
Content-Type →application/json
Date →Wed, 05 Apr 2017 16:54:18 GMT
Server →nginx
Strict-Transport-Security →max-age=604800
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
X-Content-Type-Options →nosniff
X-Rate-Limit-Limit →2000
X-Rate-Limit-Remaining →1958
X-Rate-Limit-Reset →1491411600
X-XSS-Protection →1; mode=block
{
  "status": "completed",
  "product_id": "37a94557-682f-4562-ba62-2448f80d3ddd",
  "request_id": "906cff4d-5f05-4d46-9afd-1fdce67a0378",
  "driver": null,
  "eta": null,
  "location": {
    "latitude": 28.3581827,
    "bearing": null,
    "longitude": -82.1908453
  },
  "vehicle": null,
  "surge_multiplier": 1,
  "shared": false
}
```

The same happens for v1.2, though getting an upfront fare id works fine.

**Once the current_trip_exists error is triggered, it only affects certain lat/long products. Here are some starting lat/long/productIds where the error does not occur:**

34.708101, -92.409385, 2143f90b-ce68-4f6d-a113-4872b207e626

41.354571, -81.916012, 49348f0a-c623-46c0-86eb-9c2f761e8de8

33.5840017, -111.8866007, 893cb2a1-c412-4fee-8947-dd2accbc56a1

**Once the error gets triggered using the reproduction steps above, the error occurs for many different locations. Here are some starting lat/long/product_ids where it does not go through:**

41.2562659, -96.321596, 807c3d2e-b97e-4f17-b43a-96cc0d0a1b9d

41.1259355, -74.38201289, 1b64bf82-a0ba-4b0f-be32-df8d05481d7e

35.154967, -106.6907186, a07dd25b-37f2-4a13-b4a3-1b4b27d79a77

28.947881, -81.298418, 4d68a13c-a04b-478a-bc66-5369d0e9e23a

32.24922, -110.825833, 85bbf2e4-fdf0-476d-beb4-b69022994ed3

37.896782, -122.044295, 04a497f5-380d-47f2-bf1b-ad4cfdcb51f2

37.36173, -122.0986, 57c0ff4e-1493-4ef9-a4df-6b961525cf92

34.0542439, -118.2658918, 2143f90b-ce68-4f6d-a113-4872b207e626

33.818729301, -84.812277183, 6d898741-0175-4c71-ad5f-93fc66270d6a

43.6746785, -79.3860744, d1e548ac-4be5-46c0-8c86-201ac8a36fc6

39.9921432, -83.06592479, 5ba3ede5-e093-40d4-9ca0-fa189695a9d3

30.4200452, -86.60652449, e72f2ebe-7cea-451d-bb43-b68aea182ebc

Comment: Can you make a request to /request/current when you encounter this error? Based on the error the user is actually on a trip, so I would check the current request details and if needed cancel the ongoing sandbox trip.

Comment: When we make a GET request to /request/current it says the user is not on a trip. Also, this is a real request, not happening in Sandbox. The user is not currently on a trip, when we open the app on our phone we are able to order normally.

Comment: I am struggling to reproduce this. Can you try with another user token? Can you also share the exact request/response in order?

Comment: Thanks, I've added the lat/long and productIds that are returning the 409 error. I've also tried this with several different user tokens. I'm not sure what you mean by exact request/response in order, but will update soon.

Comment: Can you share the exact request / response (minus token) and the order of the calls? I am having trouble replicating this behavior.

Comment: My suspicion is this is happening because sometimes Uber automatically reorders drivers when a driver cancels on a passenger. It makes it hard to debug. I will post an update later today. If I'm wrong I will send the exact request/response that you asked for.

Comment: In these [linked photos](http://imgur.com/a/l9Tul) you can see two different types of driver cancellation notifications. One says uber found another driver and we saved some minutes, the other says the driver had to cancel - we get charged for that. @DustinWhittle how does the api handle the first instance? Does it assign a new requestId to the new driver? Does it ever return a driver_cancellation status or does the data in the response just change?

Comment: @DustinWhittle I'm updating the question with my complete request/response including my user token. I would be concerned about fraud but the account can't be used anyways. I'll refresh it once we figure out what's up.

Comment: You should never post your token (i have edited the post). In the case the driver cancels you will get a driver_canceled webhook for the request. You will get a charge if the driver waits for 5 minutes before canceling. I am still not able to reproduce always getting a 409. I am only able to see when I am already on a trip. Just to be clear there can only be a single trip per user. Can you show the current trip details that show not on trip and the relevant request id from the trip you create. Also, it is best to use the sandbox for testing.

Comment: thank @DustinWhittle, if we make a GET request after getting a driver_canceled request will the API return a processing status if it starts looking for another driver?

Comment: also, we are only witnessing this behavior when requests are made to the production api not the sandbox, i will update with what you requested.

Comment: @DustinWhittle I updated with the GET requests

Comment: Okay, I will dive in and follow up after some more debugging.

Comment: Thanks, sorry it's so bizarre. We appreciate the help @DustinWhittle

Comment: Okay, so I dug in and figured out what is happen. The short version is that is an issue on our side that happens when a driver cancels. We will release a fix and it should be resolved. I will follow up once I have confirmed the root cause is fully resolved.

Comment: Thanks @DustinWhittle, really appreciate the help